# Is a library needed for Tesseract to detect PNG files?

Tags: c#, png, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

I'm running Tesseract 2.04 to read a PNG file but I'm getting this error:-

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine
name_to_image_type:Error:Unrecognized image type:png.png
IMAGE::read_header:Error:Can't read this image type:png.png
Tessedit:Error:Read of file failed:png.png
Signal_exit 31 ABORT. LocCode: 3  AbortCode: 3
```

I've searched everywhere and tried several things, but can't find the root cause. Some pages hint at installing some Leptonica library, but nothing specific. It seems everyone's version of Tesseract can read PNG files by default. What could I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess... does the file's name end in ".png.png"?

Comment: Some suggestions: check if that happens with PNG in any format (interlaced or not, palette or RGB or RGBA...).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Yes it's a PNG file with a bad naming structure :)

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for the tip, will check it out and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tesseract 2.04 accepts TIFF format only. It's too old, btw. Try 3.0x, which uses Leptonica to read additional image formats, including PNG.

Comment: Ahaa... The problem is 2.04 works perfectly with the input I gave, weirdly enough, 3.0 isn't as good :\